# Mixing two languages

Tags: antlr4

I am writing a grammar for a small meta language. That language should include code blocks of another language (e.g., JavaScript, C, or the like). I would like to treat these code blocks just a plain strings that are print out unchanged. My language is C/Java syntax based using `{ }` for code blocks. But I would also like to use `{` `}` for the code blocks of the embedded language. Here some example code:

```
// my language
modul Abc {
   input x: string;
   otherLang {
      // this is now a code block from the second
      // language, which I do not want to analyze
      // It might itself contain { } like
      if (something) {
          abc = "string";
      }
   }
}
```

How would I resuse `{` and `}` for those different uses without mixing them up with the ones from an embedded language?

Answer (score 1):

An interesting way to do this is to use mode recursion. ANTLR internally maintains a mode stack.

Although a bit verbose, the recursed mode offers the possibility of handling things -- like comments and escaped chars -- that could otherwise throw off the nesting.

One thing to be aware of is that rules with `more` attributes concatenate their matched content into the token produced by the first following non-`more`ed rule. The following example uses the virtual token `OTHER_END` to provide semantic clarity and preclude confusion with otherwise being a `RPAREN` token.

```
tokens {
    OTHER_END
}

otherLang : OTHER_BEG OTHER_END+ ; // multiple 'end's dependent on nesting

OTHER_BEG : 'otherLang' LPAREN -> pushMode(Other) ;
LPAREN    : LParen ;
RPAREN    : RParen ;
WS        : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

mode Other ;
    // handle special cases here 
    O_RPAREN : RParen -> type(OTHER_END), popMode() ;
    O_LPAREN : LParen -> more, pushMode(Other) ;
    O_STUFF  : .      -> more ;

fragment LParen : '{' ;
fragment RParen : '}' ;
```